# How to optimize my code in Spring MVC Controller using @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my controller,My controller method names are equals to the requestmapping url.For example,`/list` is equal to method name `list`. Is there has a common handler method to short my code?I do not want to write every controller and method in these way.I remember that .net mvc has a comom way to config it.What about Spring MVC?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/fooController ")
public class FooController {
     @RequestMapping("/list") public String list(...) { ... }
     @RequestMapping("/save") public String save(...) { ... }
     @RequestMapping("/delete") public String delete(...) { ... }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/basketballController ")
public class BasketballController {
     @RequestMapping("/list") public String list(...) { ... }
     @RequestMapping("/save") public String save(...) { ... }
     @RequestMapping("/delete") public String delete(...) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and override default code

```
protected RequestMappingInfo getMappingForMethod(Method method, Class<?> handlerType) {
    RequestMappingInfo info = createRequestMappingInfo(method);
    if (info != null) {
        RequestMappingInfo typeInfo = createRequestMappingInfo(handlerType);
        if (typeInfo != null) {
            info = typeInfo.combine(info);
        }
    }
    return info;
}
```

As you can see here it tries to resolve RequestMapping annotation from method and combine with Controller class annotation.

Just replace the logic to use method name instead.

See [here](https://github.com/mohchi/spring-security-request-mapping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mohchi/example/web/framework/ExtendedRequestMappingHanderMapping.java) a similar logic. Instead of method name security check was used.

UPDATE:

The classes to test. For me it works.
MappingHandler I use method name check because there are much more controllers, errors controllers etc. For real solution I would introduce an annotation on the controllers to exclude default spring controllers from the logic

```
public class ExtendedRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    protected RequestMappingInfo getMappingForMethod(Method method, Class<?> handlerType) {
        RequestMappingInfo info;
        if (method.getName().startsWith("test")) {
            info = createRequestMappingInfoByMethodName(method);
        }
        else {
            info = super.getMappingForMethod(method, handlerType);
        }
        return info;
    }

    protected RequestMappingInfo createRequestMappingInfoByMethodName(Method method) {
        RequestMapping requestMapping = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(method.getDeclaringClass(), RequestMapping.class);
        String path = requestMapping.value()[0] + "/" + method.getName();
        return RequestMappingInfo
                .paths(path)
                .methods(requestMapping.method())
                .params(requestMapping.params())
                .headers(requestMapping.headers())
                .consumes(requestMapping.consumes())
                .produces(requestMapping.produces())
                .mappingName(requestMapping.name())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Config to use the mapping

```
@Configuration
public class ExtendedWebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        ExtendedRequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new ExtendedRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
        handlerMapping.setInterceptors(getInterceptors());
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Override @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
        return adapter;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/common")
public class MethodNameController {
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
    public String test2() {
        return "test2";
    }
}
```

test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MethodNameControllerTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Value("${server.contextPath}")
    private String contextPath;
    private String base;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.base = "http://localhost:" + port;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodNameMappingResolving() throws Exception {
        TestRestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();
        String url = base + contextPath + "/common/test";
        String res1 = template.getForObject(url, String.class);
        assertThat(res1, equalTo("test"));

        url += "2";
        String res2 = template.getForObject(url, String.class);
        assertThat(res2, equalTo("test2"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show some of the method name logic in case the poster doesn't grok reflection?

Comment: where is createRequestMappingInfo method,please?

Comment: The answer updated. It's better to check source code of the RequestMappingHandlerMapping class

Comment: @StanislavL,It calls wrong in  createRequestMappingInfoByMethodName().The method findMergedAnnotation(Class<capture#2-of ?>, Class<RequestMapping>) is undefined for the type  AnnotatedElementUtils

Comment: I use spring-core 4.3.8.RELEASE. Guess it's something with version. I think you can just get the method's class and get RequestMapping from the class (your controller's RequestMapping annotation in fact)

Comment: @StanislavL I try to update to spring-core 4.3.8.RELEASE.The code do not calls wrong.But it seems not to work.When I debug,but it seems not to jump to the debug point.Do your code only work in spring boot?My application is spring mvc.

Comment: actually it should be no difference. I tested with spring booth though

Answer (score 0):

Will an abstract base class for both controllers work for you?

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> {
     @RequestMapping("/list") public String list(...) { ... }
     @RequestMapping("/save") public String save(...) { ... }
     @RequestMapping("/delete") public String delete(...) { ... }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/fooController ")
public class FooController extends BaseController<Foo> {      
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/basketballController ")
public class BasketballController extends BaseController<Basketball> {
}
```

Comment: It works a bit, but it's not the way  I want it.If I have some method do not in the BaseController,I have to write the original  way.

Comment: I do not quite understand what do you mean by "some method". How do you want to optimise it if it is not a common method?

Comment: Some method  means in some controller it may has export method,and in the other controller it may has other method according to the actual business.

Comment: I do not see any problems with flexible customization of its work in abstract class.

Comment: Yes,if the common method in basecontroller and the special method in single controller can use the same handler,it will  be more better.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend to `AbstractControllerUrlHandlerMapping` and override the method and add bean in web.xml.

```
  <beans:bean id="myControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" class="com.qiyongkang.sys.controller.MyControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
  <beans:property name="interceptors">
      <beans:array>
          <beans:bean id="sysLogInterceptor" class="com.qiyongkang.sys.interceptor.SysLogInterceptor"></beans:bean>
      </beans:array>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="caseSensitive" value="true" />
  <beans:property name="frameworkPackagePrefixs" value="com.qiyongkang." />
  <beans:property name="actionPackageSuffixs" value=".ctrl,.controller" />
  <beans:property name="actionClassSuffixs" value="Ctrl,Controller" />
```

Here is an [example](http://blog.csdn.net/qiyongkang520/article/details/49456649#comments).