# What is the difference between a spring request mapping and url mapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I stumbled across this question after reading the log of my spring boot applicaiton in debug mode.

At startup, the While the spring [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) is "Looking for request mappings in application context" and finds the resquest mappings defined  on my controllers. Later the [`BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html) is "Looking for URL mappings in application context" and fails to find one for every bean defined in my context (no URL paths identified)

My question is, what the difference between a request mapping and an url mapping, can someone link a documentation to read what the `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` is looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RequestMappingHandlerMapping**

According to the documentation, the [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html):

> Creates RequestMappingInfo instances from type and method-level @RequestMapping annotations in @Controller classes.

A [RequestMappingInfo](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfo.html#RequestMappingInfo-java.lang.String-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.RequestMethodsRequestCondition-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ParamsRequestCondition-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.HeadersRequestCondition-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ConsumesRequestCondition-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ProducesRequestCondition-org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.RequestCondition-) can be instantiated with the constructor:

```
public RequestMappingInfo(String name,
                          PatternsRequestCondition patterns,
                          RequestMethodsRequestCondition methods,
                          ParamsRequestCondition params,
                          HeadersRequestCondition headers,
                          ConsumesRequestCondition consumes,
                          ProducesRequestCondition produces,
                          RequestCondition<?> custom)
```

and represents a request with a set of conditions to be matched.

**BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping**

The [BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html) is an:

> Implementation of the HandlerMapping interface that map from URLs to beans with names that start with a slash ("/"),

and as a [AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.html) is:

> detecting URL mappings for handler beans through introspection of all defined beans in the application context.

Answer (score 0):

RequestMappingHandlerMapping defines all possible URLs you can process in the application. It is not necessary read the URLs from controllers annotation. The mappings could be calculated. E.g. [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982249/how-to-optimize-my-code-in-spring-mvc-controller-using-requestmapping/43982679#43982679) provides a solution when request mappings are generated on fly from method names.

RequestMapping should be comlex with e.g. `@PathParameter` when mapping text is `"\user\{userId}"`

So step 1 kind of register all URLs we can process.

Then for each the URL we need to find a bean which actually should be invoked to process some URL (to find a method which spring should call).