# Spring Boot - Get controller method name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

How can I get the called method name of a controller class in a custom authentication provider?

A REST request is calling a controller method, this request is authenticated in a custom authentication provider. How can I get the method name of the controller class in the provider?

Here is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getAllCustomers() {
    return "Get customers...";
}
```

Thats my custom authentication provider, I would like to get the name of the called controller method here:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

// ...
// get controller method here... -> getAllCustomers

return UsernamePasswordToken(username, password)
}
```

My authentication provider is configured by a class, which extends the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthProvider customAuthProvider;


    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(this.customAuthProvider);

    }
```

The custom auth provider returns an object of the class CustomAuthToken, which extedns the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. I am not calling `authenticationManager.authenticate(new MyCustomAuthenticationToken(....));`

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Where are you calling your `authenticationManager.authenticate(....)` from?

Comment: Can an AuthenticationProvider also be a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`? I know you are able to tell the controller and method attempting to be called with the `HandlerMethod`

Comment: @Leffchik this is my custom authentication provider. This provider is called when a user whats to authenticate with the service. This is configured by an class which extends the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: In general, the goal here is to get `HandlerMethod` from somewhere as been mentioned by @DarrenForsythe. But the problem is if you calling `authenticationManager.authenticate(....)` somewhere in servlet filter then I dont think that's possible, because you wont have `HandlerMetod` till `DispatcherServlet` called (And `servlet.service()` is being called after all filters)

Comment: @Leffchik yes, thats the problem, I don't have HandlerMethod...

Comment: @ftes, but if you have your custom authentication provider then you should have custom authentication token also, right?

Comment: Yes, I have a custom auth token

Comment: @ftes, so you're calling somewhere in code `authenticationManager.authenticate(new MyCustomAuthenticationToken(....));`. If so, can you tell where is it exactly, or share this code?

Comment: Why on earth would you need that? What is your use case here, generally when trying to do stuff like that you are doing things you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and track the method

```
protected RequestMappingInfo getMappingForMethod(Method method, Class<?> handlerType) {
    RequestMappingInfo info = super.getMappingForMethod(method, handlerType);

    return info;
}
```

The RequestMappingInfo keeps path(s) for the method. Just store the info in a map to be used in your provider. The RequestMappingHandlerMapping could be autowired.

See [How to optimize my code in Spring MVC Controller using @RequestMapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982249/how-to-optimize-my-code-in-spring-mvc-controller-using-requestmapping)